# Nautilus window opens after device usb connection

Tags: usb, nautilus

Nautilus window opens after device usb connection. But this is not a storage device. It's even not mounted. It just takes some power supply via USB.
How to disable automatic window opening after **not mounting**?

Answer (score 0):

#### GUI

Bring up a terminal window, then install `dconf-editor` package.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor && dconf-editor
```

Navigate to `org > gnome > desktop > media-handling`, uncheck **automount-open** option on the key list.

[image]

#### Command line

No need to install anything, simply run following command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
```